# Ubuntu, mysql server connection

Tags: linux, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

Hello everybody please ignore my noobness,

My problem start from connecting to mysql on ubuntu 12.04

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

and after debugging and googling i found following in error.log,

```
130714 11:23:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
130714 11:23:45 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130714 11:23:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130714 11:23:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130714 11:23:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibcN8p9L' (Errcode: 13)
130714 11:23:45  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
130714 11:23:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130714 11:23:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130714 11:23:45 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130714 11:23:45 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here is my some of configurations of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

Here is my diskspace information which i get by running `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         20G  2.0G   17G  11% /
udev            246M  4.0K  246M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  200K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            248M     0  248M   0% /run/shm
```

Here is my memory utilization details

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           495         93        401          0         16         49
-/+ buffers/cache:         28        467
Swap:            0          0          0
```

When i run `mysql_install_db` or `mysql_upgrade` (as it says in error details) it gives me

```
Installing MySQL system tables...

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the /usr/scripts/mysqlbug script!
```

I have googled alot, some says to reboot and then start mysql service, some suggests to re-install mysql but still i am unable to make it correct. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_bak
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo netstat -anp | grep 3306
```

Essentially you're backing up your MySQL data directory, then re-initialising it and starting MySQL. The netstat command will check for any processes listening on port 3306.

Also check the error.log again if you have issues starting MySQL.

Comment: thanks Watson, i have updated the question, when i run mysql_install_db or mysql_upgrade it gives me error as i updated in question.

Comment: No problem - can you also add the permissions of `/tmp`, as shown by `ls -l / | grep tmp`?

Comment: thanks Watson it has resolve the issue the only issue with which i left is 403 Error of apache, it says

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

and in error.log it says, 

)Permission denied: /root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Would you please guide me i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: This does beyond the scope of the original question - though as a free pointer, you shouldn't be using `/root` for your document root - try `/var/www` instead.

Comment: Watson any know how about this much appreciated; http://serverfault.com/questions/523229/passenger-is-listing-all-the-public-folder-files

Answer (score 0):

I would first off try what the error line suggests, as in "Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.".

Then, I would check the diskspace on your mysql partition by running `df -h` and making sure there is enough space available. Also run `htop` or `free -m` to check your memory utilization for `tmpfs` and make sure you have enough space. Unable to write to `tmp` space in one of those lines implies a space issue.

There looks to also be a problem with usage of innoDB, so that's something that may need further investigation.

Also make sure MySQL is running at the time. I am assuming you cannot start MySQL, judging by your comment, however.

Comment: thanks Peter for you quick response, i have updated the question will you please tell me whats the issue now ? i have triend "mysql_upgrade" but it gives me the same error of socket.