# passenger is listing all the public folder files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Hello everyone please ignore my noobness, this is very first time i am deploying RailsApp;

I have used apache and phussion passenger with rvm, here is my virtual host configurations that i added in apache2.conf,

Before this it was giving me forbidden access error 403, i googled and found that it is permissions issue so i run `chmod -R 640 /root` and after that it started listing my public folder files.

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.8/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.8
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mydoctor
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /root/mydoctor/public    
      <Directory /root/mydoctor/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions please, much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Stop misusing the `root` user for general tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange to have a webroot in `/root`.  Typically this folder, being root's home directory, is a folder used for things only root may have any access at all to; you may have created a security risk.

If you want to prevent directory listings from being shown, you should add the `-Indexes` option to your options directive for the directory (which is currently just `-MultiViews`).

You may also want to set a default document or something; otherwise instead of a directory listing you will just get a `403 Forbidden` error.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the followings lines to VirtualHost-apache.conf:

```
Options +Indexes
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
```

this should stay as follows:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.8/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-4.0.8
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
<VirtualHost *:80>
      Options +Indexes
      ServerName mydoctor
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /root/mydoctor/public    
      <Directory /root/mydoctor/public>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride all
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
      RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

save the settings and restart apache2